# node-red-node-aws output node filename property

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, node-red

New to node-red, and just trying this node for the 1st time.

Flow is as follows

```
[{"id":"2f6b5f38.045e2","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"4e1d163a.a3b598","type":"amazon s3 out","z":"2f6b5f38.045e2","aws":"","bucket":"testbucket","filename":"","localFilename":"local_file.txt","region":"us-east-1","name":"AWS S3","x":700,"y":380,"wires":[]},
{"id":"be311fd.6ce07e","type":"inject","z":"2f6b5f38.045e2","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":240,"y":440,"wires":[["f6cce006.47462"]]},
{"id":"f6cce006.47462","type":"change","z":"2f6b5f38.045e2","name":"","rules":[{"t":"move","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"filename","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":450,"y":480,"wires":[["4e1d163a.a3b598"]]}]
```

I want the timestamp to be used as the filename but can't seem to figure out how to make the AWS node take the `msg.filename` property as the filename.

As per documentation "*Amazon S3 out node.
Uploads content to an Amazon S3 bucket. The bucket name can be specified in the node bucket property or in the msg.bucket property. **The filename on Amazon S3 is taken from the node filename property or the msg.filename property.** The content is taken from either the node `localFilename` property, the `msg.localFilename` property or the `msg.payload` property.*"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-web-nodes/blob/master/aws/aws.js#L203), as long as the filename property in the nodes config is empty then it should use the `msg.filename` for the filename.

If you include a filename in the configuration then this will always be used.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I though too, but it’s not what is happening.  It fails and sometimes crashes node-red itself.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was passing a number in msg.filename and not a string.  Once converted to string the AWS node works.